# Terminal buffer is being treated as editor buffer

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

I am using vim-terminal plugin. When I create a split terminal using the command `:TerminalSplit bash`, I can input commands into the terminal, but when I press enter, it moves to the next line without executing the command. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Please include a link to the plugin and your version. You might be better off using the native `:terminal` family of commands, which should work correctly out of the box